# Tiling specifically named windows/applications

Tags: vbscript

I am attempting to tile two windows horizontally, i.e. the equivalent of selecting two programs from the Task Manager and selecting tile horizontally.

At present I can achieve this with VBScript only by minimising all windows and then restoring the two that I would like to be tiled, as per the below code.

Is there anyway to tile two applications of specific name using VBScript (or otherwise) without minimising everything and without having to load the application through VBScript?

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.MinimizeALL
WScript.Sleep 500 
Set shl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shl.AppActivate "Application 1"
WScript.Sleep 500  
shl.SendKeys "% r"
WScript.Sleep 500  
shl.AppActivate "Application 2"
shl.SendKeys "% r"
WScript.Sleep 500  
objShell.TileVertically  
Set shl = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
```